# Sending a message to all contacts in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I need to send a message to all my contacts (309 phone numbers) via WhatsApp.

Is there a way to send a message for all my contacts, because the application just allows 25 contacts at once?

Answer (score 9):

Use the broadcast function, see: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23130793

1. Open WhatsApp
2. Press the [Menu Button]
3. Tap [New broadcast]
4. Type your contacts' names or press the [+] button to choose from your contact
   list
5. Tap [Next]
6. Type your message and optionally attach media
7. Tap  the send button

Comment: will it send the message an an individual message to all, or a group message? will they come to know that it has been sent to others too?

Comment: No, others will be unaware about your broadcast. They will get message in separate chat.

Comment: But limitation of this is, If user added in broadcast is not having your number saved in his contact list, he may not get your message.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible since it's a limitation of the app itself. The best you can do is to put a status message so everyone can see, but you won't know for sure. Or you message them in groups of 25.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest is to select:

1. Chat icon at the bottom screen
2. Broadcast list OR new Group at the top screen
3. Create your contacts